# False roots obtained from Solving system of non linear equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus

[image: graph]I wrote a code to get the roots of systems of non-linear equations .It gives me right roots but there are equations gives me wrong/false roots that are very close to right ones .What is the reason and solution for this problem?
see attached figure to understand my problem.
note that my code stops iteration loop after getting solutions with 5% error ,so it stops after getting 0.001 root but it is a false root

Comment: can you post your system?

Comment: Sounds like round-off error to me. But you might  get a better answer on a coding site (if you provide your code).

Comment: The method to solve non-linear equations might be numerically unstable. Please also show the equations causing the error.

Comment: I will add a picture to my post to illustrate my problem because I do not have the equations right now. I need to get solutions to overcome this problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is not false but a complex root.

When your solution method is set up to capture real variable roots and when the curve has a minimum (or a maximum) the way you have shown with tangent parallel to $x-$ axis.. it points to the existence of a complex root in the neighborhood with real part of complex root while the curve evades intersection with x-axis... as a hint to you.

However if you switch to a complex independent variable that will be fully captured.